# How to book a train ticket from Tblisi to Baku (online)

Tags: tickets, georgia-country, train-stations, tbilisi, baku

So as per my research, there is a train that goes from Tbilisi to Baku. I want to book the ticket online from Tbilisi to Baku. So I came across this website http://www.railway.ge/ which seems to be their official website for booking. But the issue here is that, I cant find city name "Baku" option at the destination dropdown on the page. Although this [page](http://www.railway.ge/modzraobis-saerto-ganrigi/.com) says that there is this international train that goes from Tbilisi to Baku.

How would I book online? any suggestions

Comment: railway.ge are only for domestic trains, it isn't possible to book international trains there (e.g. to Yerevan, Baku).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to use the Azerbaijan one.  To find this, I went to [Rome2Rio](https://www.rome2rio.com/map/Tbilisi/Baku)'s page on Tbilisi to Baku.  This then shows the train option with Azerbaijan Railways (ADDY)

Duration
    12h 10m

Estimated Price
    $6 - $20 USD

Frequency
    Once daily

And links to [the rail website](https://ticket.ady.az/en/movement) showing movement of the trains.

However it notes that "Buy tickets at the station", indicating possibly it's not possible online currently for cross-border tickets.